# Typed Arrays byte offset

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

Even though the byte offset is 12, and the underlying buffer size is of 12 bytes, how are we able to set the starting of `int8Array` beyond the underlying buffersize?

```js
let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(12);
const intArray = new Int32Array(buffer);
console.log(intArray.buffer);
const int8Array = new Int8Array(buffer, 12);
int8Array[0] = 200;
console.log(intArray.buffer);
```

How is `const int8Array = new Int8Array(buffer, 12)` possible?

I was expecting a

> RangeError: RangeError: Start offset 12 is outside the bounds of the buffer

Answer (score 1):

The `buffer` which is an `ArrayBuffer` has size of **12 bytes**. So the available index would be **1** to **11**. Any index after **11** would be out of bounds.

When you create `Int8Array` with the **offset** of **12 bytes**, It will skip **12 bytes** from the `buffer`. But there is nothing after **11th index** in the `buffer`, It will create an empty `Int8Array` with the length of **0**.

Even though the size of `Int8Array` is **0**, Still you can assign value by executing,

```
int8Array[0] = 200;
```

Comment: But if I change the byte offset from **12** to **13**, then why can it not do this: "**When you create `Int8Array` with the offset of 12 bytes, It will skip 12 bytes from the buffer. But there is nothing after 11th index in the buffer, It will create an empty Int8Array with the length of 0.**"
Instead it throws the error this time: 
`RangeError: Start offset 13 is outside the bounds of the buffer`

Comment: I know this is weird but that is how it is implemented. When you specify `offset` it should be within the bounds limit. Because by setting offset you specify the start point (by skipping offset) of the array, So exceeding the bound limit will obviously throws error.